# webscrapping for a discord bot not sending answer correctly

Tags: java, discord.js, cheerio

first post here , I would like help for a code I am currently working on everything works just fine except for the last part.
When it comes to sending the message with the desired url the only thing that comes out is unusable
the text that comes out is [object Object].

here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const config = require("./data/config.json");

const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const { map } = require("cheerio/lib/api/traversing");

const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });

client.login(config.token);

client.on("ready", () => console.log("bot is online"));

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {

    console.log(message.content);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix))return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "wiki") {
            
        const name  = (`${args[0]}`)

        
        const meta = {

            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.25/xml"
        };

        const headers = new fetch.Headers(meta);

 const webscraper = async () => {

            const response = await fetch(`https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=${name}&scope=internal&navigationSearch=true`);

            const body = await response.text();

            const $ = cheerio.load(body);

            const result = $(".unified-search__results")

                .children()
                .map(function(i, el) {

                    return {

                        
                        link: $(this).find(".unified-search__result__link").text(),

                    }
                })
                .toArray();

                console.log(result)
                message.reply(`test ${result}`)
        };

        webscraper();
    }
    else (message.reply(`I am sorry ${message.member} but the command "${command}" is not finished or doesn't exist`))
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it isn't on the my issue at hand, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you indicate, perhaps with a comment, precisely where in the code your problem is occurring?

Comment: It seems you try to stringify an array here: `message.reply(\`test ${result}\`)`. `result` is an array of objects and those are shown as `[object Object]` when converted to a string. As I've got no idea what the scraped data is or how you want to send it, I can't really help.

Comment: Note that Java and Javascript are two totally unrelated languages. Please make sure to correctly tag your questions. Otherwise, you will get attention only by the wrong audience.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by [Zsolt Meszaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373/zsolt-meszaros) i was trying to extract a array instead of a string, after a bit of researched all I had to do was stringify the array with:

```
const url = result[0];
let urlstring = JSON.stringify(url);
```

and the message would be printed in discord under a readable format thank you.